# How to add this weird CSS styling

Tags: css, wordpress

I was trying to add some css styling to my wordpress website. However, I'm quite confused how to select the element and add the css !
Let me explain it in detals in three scenarios:
Picture 1:
[image]

I'm going to change the color and width of that button with text "Submit your attendance" inside. I wanted to make it red.

**First Try: Picture 2:**

[image]

I selected the calss which is :

```
wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit
```

Added the background-color: red , but it didn't work.

**Second Try: Picture 3:**
[image]

I did the same for this class:

```
wpcf7-form-control
```

**Thrd Try: Pictur 4:**
[image]

In inline style, when I add background-color: red and width: 100% in workes. I noticed a style attribute is also added. However, I'm not sure how to add in my Custom CSS of wordpress. I mean which element should I select? Of course Inline-style is not an element.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with regard to WordPress. This is due to CSS Specificity.  What this means is that the rule that is more specific will "win" and be applied. This is why inline styles typically work over non-inline styles.

In your example, the rule that is being applied is more specific than the one you're trying to override with.

There is a hierarchy when it comes to specificity and the order in which rules are applied. Here they are in order of most specific to less:

1. Inline Styles
2. Ids - targeting the ID of an element is more specific than targeting a class
3. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes (for example :hover)
4. Elements (for example a "p" tag) and pseudo-elements (:before)

Either add an ID for the your button or target the class in a more specific manner.  For example `body .thecontainer .thediv .anothercontainer .myelement`

Answer (score 0):

This might be work. You need to add !important property. 
wpcf7-form-control{ background-color:red !important; }
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

To update worpress css you have to edit the file style.css

Appearance -> Editor -> style.css (search inside other files)

or

Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS (where you have to add manually every line of code)

Sometimes you need to add "!important;" at the end of line, something like:

background-color: red!important;

Comment: I would not update CSS through the admin. The next update of your theme will overwrite your changes.

Comment: Well, sure, but next step should be

"wp_dequeue_style"